# Python setup.py doesn't install to virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools, distutils

I'm trying to get the hang of developing distributable Python packages. I have a simple `setup.py` script that looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='foo',
    version='1.0',
    py_modules=['foo'],
)
```

If I activate the virtualenv for this project and run `setup.py develop` it installs to my global `site-packages` -- not the virtualenv. If I pass in the env's site package directory using `--install-dir`, it gives the error

```
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

C:\Users\men\Envs\foo\Lib\site-packages
```

Isn't the venv's activate script supposed to set this up?

Comment: Do you run `python setup.py develop`?

Comment: Yes I ran `setup.py develop` (since I'm on Windows)

Comment: I am not on a windows, so unfortunately, I cannot check. But how should `setup.py` know, which python interpreter to use? I think you cannot omit `python`, if you want to make sure the right python interpreter (i.e. the interpreter from the venv) is used.

Comment: You are absolutely right - thank you! If you want to answer I'll accept :)